# How can I write something between two minipages?

Tags: minipage

I have created minipages and I want to write a simple word `AND` between these two minipages without disturbing vertical and horizontal alignments. How can I make it possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_1 , y_1\right)&=\left(\dfrac{2+2}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{4+4}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(2 , 4\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_2 , y_2\right)&=\left(\dfrac{4+4}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{2+2}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(4 , 2\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: minipages are just boxes, so write the text between them. However, if the line gets too long it will be broken, like every line. Your minipages already occupy the full `\textwidth`. Change the factor `0.5` e.g. to `0.4` and write `and` between `\end{minipage}` and `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: you have two minipages each half a linewidth wide but they do not fit on a line as you have paragraph indentation to the left and a word space in between. Do you want them all on one line with `and` in between, or arranged vertically with `and` in the middle row?

Comment: @David Carlisle Sir i wanna place AND in the middle at the top between 2 minipages

Comment: @gernot it works but the word AND appear at the bottom.

Comment: it is bottom aligned because you have `[b]`

Comment: What is the next modification?

Comment: I wanna place that word in the same line of (x1.y1) and (x2,y2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial markup did not fit on a line

```
Overfull \hbox (20.2359pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--22
```

due to extra white space added to the left and between the boxes.

Removing that white space and making the boxes smaller allows the word to fit.

I allowed the default centre alignment, you could use `[t]` instead of `[b]` but it looked a bit high

[image]

I would never force the two blocks this far apart it has no advantages and just makes it a lot harder for the reader to scan the page, but this is, I think, the layout that you ask for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_1 , y_1\right)&=\left(\dfrac{2+2}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{4+4}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(2 , 4\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}%
\hfill and\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_2 , y_2\right)&=\left(\dfrac{4+4}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{2+2}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(4 , 2\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok sir@ this work is very useful for me infact the output is nearly equal to what i want.

Comment: in this case, wouldn't it simply be better to treat this as an unnumbered equation, and use a couple of `{aligned}[t]` blocks with `\text{and}` in the middle, so that it would be base-aligned?

Comment: @barbarabeeton  something like that yes, that would give more reasonable spacing not splat it all out full width.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple put another minipage. Generally you can use as much minipage as you want. You can align it  as you want inside this minipage
by changing the number inside \vspace{}.
For example see below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.42\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_1 , y_1\right)&=\left(\dfrac{2+2}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{4+4}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(2 , 4\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.06\textwidth}
    \vspace{-10mm}and
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
        \begin{flalign*}
        \left(x_2 , y_2\right)&=\left(\dfrac{4+4}{2}\;\;,\;\;\dfrac{2+2}{2}\right)\\[6pt]
        &=\left(4 , 2\right)
        \end{flalign*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but how can move that word verically, i mean move it above

Comment: this line is now even more overfull than the original (47.7pt) it has `1.05\textwidth` frmm the minipages, a `\parindent` of 15pt and two word spaces